# Mac OS X 10.5 App "not supported on this architecture" cured by copying?

Tags: macos, compatibility, osx-leopard, powerpc

I have an app that updates itself over the internet, and the updated copy won't run on PowerPC machines (G5) running Leopard (10.5.8).  Double-clicking the app produces a message saying "You can't open the application "*appname*" because it is not supported on this architecture."  But here's the weird part:  if I duplicate the app using the Finder or using a `cp -R` command, then the duplicate runs fine!  And yet, if I do `ls -laeR` on both apps, the results are identical.  I restarted the machine, and the difference between the two copies was still there.

Sometimes, renaming the app made it run.  After a few tries, I managed to rename it back to the original name and still have it run.

If this was just on one machine, I'd dismiss it as disk corruption, cosmic rays, or a voodoo hex, but it was reported by a customer and then I reproduced it on my own machine.

Any ideas what could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the Launch Services database had somehow flagged the app as unsupported, which I verified by using the semi-secret `lsregister` command line tool to dump the database.  Anything that would change the mod date of the app, such as `touch`, sufficed to make Launch Services wake up and smell the coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like an extended attribute or some other aspect that isn't being carried over to the duplicate of the program files.

Maybe try looking into running the `xattr` command on the output of `ls -laeR` on the app bundle?